# Should I avoid to use Rc and RefCell when possible in Rust?

Tags: rust

Rust offers borrow check at compile time. But if using `Rc` and `RefCell`, the check will be defered at runtime and a panic will be thrown when the program breaks the rule. Just like this:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn func1(reference: Rc<RefCell<String>>){
    let mut a = reference.borrow_mut();
    *a = String::from("func1");
    func2(reference.clone());
}

fn func2(reference: Rc<RefCell<String>>){
    let mut a = reference.borrow_mut();
    *a = String::from("func2");
    func3(reference.clone());
}

fn func3(reference: Rc<RefCell<String>>){
    let mut a = reference.borrow_mut();
    *a = String::from("func3");
}


fn main() {
    let a = Rc::new(RefCell::new(String::from("hello")));
    func1(a.clone());
}
```

This code is still leaving the bug (maybe not a bug) to runtime and panicked. So should I avoid using `Rc` and `RefCell` as much as possible? And does this code count as safe code?

Comment: Depends on your particular situation. Some things cannot be easily done with just references and compile time borrowing

Comment: The guideline is to try to do it the Rustacean compile-time way, if it's too hard, look for runtime borrowing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Rc` and `RefCell` allow you to compile code that will potentially panic at runtime, they're not to be used lightly. You could use `try_borrow_mut` instead of `borrow_mut` to avoid the panic and handle the result yourself.

That being said, even if you prevent all panicking, `Rc` and `RefCell` have a cost at runtime since they keep a reference counter. In many cases you can avoid them by rewriting your code in a more rusty way.

```rust
fn func1(mut string: String) -> String {
    string = "func1".into();
    func2(string)
}

fn func2(mut string: String) -> String {
    string = "func2".into();
    func3(string)
}

fn func3(string: String) -> String {
    "func3".into()
}

fn main() {
    let a = func1("hello".into());
}
```

Is much simpler, and safe. Rust will take care of optimizations for you.

To answer your last question, using `borrow_mut` is not considered as unsafe code since the code compiles even with the `#![forbid(unsafe_code)]` directive

Comment: Wouldn't passing Strings around be worse for performance than incrementing a reference counter?

Comment: No, strings are passed by reference so it's cheap to move them around

Comment: Is this article outdated, then? https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-rust-string-str, it states "If you pass around owned String instances instead of mutable borrows (&mut String) or read-only views of them (&str), a lot more allocations will be triggered and a lot more memory has to be kept around."

Comment: In this specific case, the ownership of the String transfers, the Strings are moved. But the question in the title is a bit more general and the topic of Strings is particularly interesting in regards to memory cost.